Add transition effect on height:auto
In nuxt, I don't know the height of an element. Is there any way to achieve a height transition effect?

Click the button, the element height is 0
Click the button again, the element is displayed at the original height

１．Use ref and nextTick: Get the actual height of the element when it is expanded and save it.
２．Dynamically set max-height: Control the height of the element by setting max-height to achieve the transition effect of expansion and collapse.

Use element-plus's el-collapse-transition
<el-collapse-transition>
  <div v-show="open">
    // your content
  </div>
</el-collapse-transition>


Like this, it dynamically toggles the element’s height between 0 and its full height using scrollHeight for smooth transitions, controlled by a simple expanded state.
<template>
  <div ref="content" :style="{ height: expanded ? $refs.content.scrollHeight + 'px' : '0', transition: 'height 0.5s ease' }">
    Put your content here...
  </div>
  <button @click="expanded = !expanded">Toggle</button>
</template>

<script setup>
const expanded = ref(false);
</script>

